# Add a variable in a post

Tags: posts, variables

I would like to control a number inside multiple wordpress posts only by changing a variable. This variable can be anywhere inside wordpress or any document accessed by ftp.

Comment: Could you [`edit` your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/267220/edit) specifically using the [*edit*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/267220/edit) link above to add in some additional information? What does this variable do exactly? Where does it show up? How are you wanting to "change" the variable, via FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set up a shortcode. You can add this either in your theme's functions.php, or as a plugin:

```
add_shortcode('varnumber', 'my_var_number');
function my_var_number($atts, $content = null) {
    return 'Put whatever number you want here instead of this text';
}
```

Wherever you want the number to appear, use the shortcode `[varnumber]` in the content. Whenever you need to change the number you'll be able to change it in just one location (your theme or plugin, whichever you chose).

You could go a step farther and set the number in the database if you want. Perhaps set up a wp-admin dashboard widget where you save the number, and then adjust the `my_var_number` function to pull it from the database instead of your theme or plugin.

Updated per comments: yes, you can have a shortcode within a shortcode. The outer shortcode needs to use `do_shortcode($content)` in order for this to work. I don't know what your initial outer shortcode looks like, but hopefully this will illustrate what needs to be present:

```
add_shortcode('outershortcode', 'create_outer_shortcode');
function create_outer_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $before = '<div class="outershortcode">';
    $after = '</div>';
    return $before . do_shortcode($content) . $after;
}
```

Your shortcode will be different, but wherever you see `$content` just make sure it's wrapped in `do_shortcode()` so it will process the shortcode inside when you call it like this:

```
[outershortcode][varnumber][/outershortcode]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!!! But this variable is inside another shortcode. I suppose it is not possible to have one shortcode inside another... Any other solution?

Comment: Yes, you can nest shortcodes - I've updated the answer, hopefully you can adjust as needed.